# How to optimize CListCtrl LVN_GETDISPINFO for non-visible columns?

Tags: listview, winapi, mfc

Using a LVS_OWNERDATA CListCtrl with more columns than are visible on the screen, how can I optimize the LVN_GETDISPINFO callback to do as little work as possible for columns (subitems) that are not currently visible because they are scrolled off of the left or right edge?

Without going to OwnerDraw, can I stop the framework from calling LVN_GETDISPINFO for columns that are not on the screen?

What is the best way to calculate in the LVN_GETDISPINFO or LVN_ODCACHEHINT callback which columns (subitems) are visible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot stop the ListView from requesting data for non-visual columns.  But you can use [`LVM_GETSUBITEMRECT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761075.aspx) to determine if a given subitem is beyond the bounds of the ListView's visible client area.

Comment: Adding a check for column visibility using GetSubItemRect on a LVN_ODCACHEHINT message works well and I should be able to handle reordered columns. I came across a suggestion to use LVM_HITTEST for just the left and right edges, but this works well.

Answer (score 0):

Check the column header item rectangle for iSubitem in LVN_GETDISPINFO and compare against the scroll position to skip work for non-visible columns

```
// In LVN_GETDISPINFO handler...
NMLVDISPINFO *pDispInfo = reinterpret_cast<NMLVDISPINFO*>(pNMHDR);
if (pDispInfo->item.mask & LVIF_TEXT) {
    CRect myListRect, headerRect; 
    myList.GetClientRect(&myListRect);
    myList.GetHeaderCtrl()->GetItemRect(pDispInfo->item.iSubitem,&headerRect);
    int hScrollPos = myList.GetScrollPos(SB_HORIZ);

    if(headerRect.right < hScrollPos || headerRect.left > hScrollPos + myListRect.right) {
        strcpy_s(pDispInfo->item.pszText,pDispInfo->item.cchTextMax,"");
        *pResult = 0;
        return;
    }
    // else, build response string
}
```